# ReadProcessMemory trouble not updating

Tags: c++

This program does work at start, but than goes wrong after few loops

I am having trouble with ReadProcessMemory. It works at beginning of my program and reads in large string, but than it stops updating the values correctly. For example it will keep the previous string and stay with that string for rest of program or it will have completely nothing in the string until I shut program off. This happens at random times after first two times it works. The basic address contains a string of text of an item through hover effect in game. However readprocessmemory seems to stop working after few times and I have double checked that the address is still updating the correct values through cheat engine and it is but it is not updating correctly in program. I know code is badly written and I should use vectors etc...

The Problem occurs here:

```
while(temp.size() < 150 ){
do{
//  memset(&buffer[0], 0, sizeof(buffer));
    ReadProcessMemory(hProcHandle, (LPCVOID)myaddr, &buffer, sizeof(buffer), NULL);
    temp = std::string((char*)buffer);
}
while(temp == previous);        
std:: cout << temp.size() << std::endl;
}
```

The above code was not a loop before, I tried recalling it again until it has new value or not null,however once the program stops working with bad values it just remains stuck in loop no matter how many times I call it, but the same address in cheat engine is being updated at same time, I have double checked that. The main problem in this loop is that readprocessmemory continues to have the same value as previous call and stays that way until shut down the program. The address is being updated in game at same time this is running.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <string>
#include <ctime> 
#include <sstream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
DWORD ariaBase = 0x400000 + 0x009B5A20;


std::string teatime[] = {" + 5 E"," + 6 Acc"," + 5 Acc"," + 6  Acc"," + 5  Acc"," + 7 Crit"," + 6 Damage"," + 5 Damage"," + 4 Damage"," + 3 Crit"};
unsigned char* buffer[800] = {0};
std::string temp = "";
std::string previous = "";
int myaddr = 0;
bool match[5];
DWORD aOffset[] = {0x724, 0x37C, 0x0, 0xAC, 0x50};
int count = 0;
std::vector<std::string> stats;
bool statsFound = false;


void WriteToMemory(HANDLE hProcHandle){ 

stats.clear();
temp = "";


while(temp.size() < 150 ){
    do{
    //  memset(&buffer[0], 0, sizeof(buffer));
        ReadProcessMemory(hProcHandle, (LPCVOID)myaddr, &buffer, sizeof(buffer), NULL);
        temp = std::string((char*)buffer);
    }
    while(temp == previous);        
    std:: cout << temp.size() << std::endl;
}
previous = temp;
std::replace( temp.begin(), temp.end(),(char)'\\', '*');
stats = findStats(temp);

//for( std::vector<std::string>::const_iterator i = stats.begin(); i != stats.end(); ++i)std::cout << *i << ' ' << std::endl;

}


int main(){         
            ...code...
            ...code...
            ...code...
            ...code...
            while(statsFound == false){
                round++;
            checkItem();
            Sleep(2000);
            WriteToMemory(hProcHandle);
            std::cout << round << std::endl;    
            for( std::vector<std::string>::const_iterator i = stats.begin(); i != stats.end(); ++i)std::cout << *i << ' ' << std::endl;

                for(int i = 0; i < stats.size();i++){
                    for(int j = 0; j < 10;j++){
                        if(("Identified Attribute:" + teatime[j]) == stats[i])match[i] = true; 
                    }

                }
                count = 0;
                for(int i = 0; i < stats.size();i++){
                    if(match[i] != true)statsFound = false;
                    else count++;

                    if(count == stats.size())statsFound = true;

                }
                match[0] = false;
                match[1] = false;
                match[2] = false;
                match[3] = false;

                if(statsFound == false)MouseStart();
            }
            ...code...
            ...code...
            ...code...

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you say what resides in the memory of the target process from which you're reading the data?
Have you heard about [GetLastError](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms679360%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function? Call it immediately after ReadProcessMemory returns and that may give a clue.

Comment: A very large string resides in the address. Address is correct and does work and updates itself in cheat engine but does not work 100% of the time when I call it in the program with ReadProcessMemory. It only works few times. The Amount of times it works is random.

Comment: If the remote data may change the access to it must be synchronised between both processes. What does GetLastError say by the way?

Comment: Seems to say 6 for Invalid Handle

Comment: Am I suppose to update the handle, Thought it would remain same when program starts up

Comment: Handle needs to be maintained too: if the target process is gone and re-launched, the handle must be re-opened of course. But even with the persistent process the access to its memory must be synchronised (using named mutex, for instance).

Comment: Thank you , It seems to be working now that handle is being updated. I did not think I needed to update it since I am not changing anything after start up besides hover effect values.